# How do I limit an integer to a maxium value in PHP?

Tags: php, integer, limit

I am unsure if a function exists already because while searching for limiting an integer to a maximum number all I found was results for what the maximum number an integer can hold.

I am looking for the function (if it exists) to replace the intLimit in the following code:

```
<?php
    $x = intLimit(1,20); // $x = 1;
    $x = intLimit(9.6,20); // $x = 9.6;
    $x = intLimit(41,20); // $x = 20;
    $x = intLimit(1932,20); // $x = 20;
    $x = intLimit(21,20); // $x = 20;

    $x = intLimit(1,40); // $x = 1;
    $x = intLimit(9.6,40); // $x = 9.6;
    $x = intLimit(41,40); // $x = 40;
    $x = intLimit(1932,40); // $x = 40;
    $x = intLimit(21,40); // $x = 21;
?>
```

Comment: Downvote and close without any reason?

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoters specifically, but this appears to be a trivial problem, so it's not clear whether what you've asked is actually what you want. Since you've accepted an answer, it seems that the simple interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: Use the ternary operator  $x = $Z > $Y ? $Y : $Z;

Answer (score 0):

Use [`filter_var()`](https://www.php.net/filter_var)

```
if (!filter_var($int, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('options' => array('min_range' => 0, 'max_range' => 50)))) {
    // greater than 50...too large
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit heavyweight for a simple limiting function.